# Does malloc use the data or text segment or another type of memory?

Tags: c

```
char *p1 = "hello";
char *p2 = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
char *p3 = "bye";

strcpy(p2, p1);
printf("p2:%s, %p\n", p2, p2);

strcpy(p2, p3); 
printf("p2:%s, %p\n", p2, p2);
```

Comment: _what kind of memory when use `malloc()` function ?_ `malloc()` points to memory which was allocated by **heap** section of the RAM.

Comment: The addresses returned by `malloc` and related functions come from whatever area your run-time environment uses for dynamic memory.  On Unix, the traditional way this is handled is by making a system call (`brk` or `sbrk`) that extends the limit of the data segment, but that is very system-specific.

Comment: @Achal In most environments, there is no "heap" section of the RAM.  That implies it's associated with specific physical addresses.  In a typical user environment, it's associated with virtual addresses, as managed by the operating system.  And as I explained, on Unix this is traditionally handled by dynamically extending the data segment.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are looking for your terminology, as it can depend a little on the platform or tools, but `text segment` usually refers to the code segment, and `malloc` definitely does not allocate memory from the code segment. That's where the code is. Also, `data segment` often (perhaps not always) refers to pre-initialized data (*e.g.*, if you declare `int x = 3;`) so if that's the case, that would also be incorrect. `malloc` would allocate memory out of general RAM which is, in some cases, referred to as `bss` (uninitialized RAM).

Comment: Yes @TomKarzes I agree about _dynamically extending the data segment_ on unix & that's a heap segment.

Comment: thank you guys. and sorry i don't know about OS and Compiler in details.
but i knew memory by malloc function is modifiable.

Comment: Just the standard comment: You don't cast the return of `malloc` and friends in C. It's mandatory in C++, but in plain old C, it's actually frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged the question with C without reference to any operating system or CPU.

The concepts of data segment and text segment are not related to C, they are related to some operating systems that make this distinction.

Of course, as the text segment, on systems that use it, is for code and read-only data, and the memory returned by malloc can be modified, it can't be the text segment.

The data segment can refer to the initialized data, malloc of course allocates new data, so it can't be this meaning of data segment.

If your definition of data segment is any data, then the returned memory is part of that. There are some (uncommon/old) architectures with separate code and data address spaces.

The C standard only promises that the malloc memory is modifiable and properly aligned.